# PostgreSQL add constraint based on FK association from a different table

Tags: postgresql, constraints, sql-function

I want to add a constraint where **only** `account_id` that has `role_id = 2` can be added to Topic.

Example: the account_id 38, who has the role_id = 1, cannot be added as an author to the Topic table.

I came up with the code below but need help to split it into a Function that verifies the role number, to only then check for that function.

Other suggestions are welcome

```
alter table topic
add constraint limited_access check (author_id in (select role_id from account where role_id = '2'))

ERROR:  cannot use subquery in check constraint
SQL state: 0A000
```

[image: TOPIC table]

[image: ACCOUNT table]

Comment: What is your Postgres version ?

Comment: PostgreSQL 13.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Comment: In that case you could create a virtual column with `my_two INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS as (2)`, and use that in a FK constraint. (I don't have a PG version >=12 here, so I cannot test it)